# How to make QTextEdit automatically save text in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

How can I make QTextEdit save whatever I type into it **automatically** without having to click a button? Is it possible to do it in PyQt5? So far I have only been able to do it with button binding.

```
def save_text():
    text=textedit.toPlainText()
    with open('mytextfile.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(text)

button.clicked.connect(save_text)
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Generally editors save when necessary, for example, press `Ctrl + S` to indicate that the file is updated. The task of updating when a letter is added or removed is heavy.

Comment: I'm making a text editor that has an autocomplete. The data will be from what I have typed in the text editor itself. So I don't need to press a button or Ctrl+S first for the autocompleter to run with an updated data. Is it possible to do it in PyQt5?  Is it too heavy for my computer to process?

Comment: Do you have a better way of doing it? Please help me.

Comment: I do not understand, I do not see the relationship with the autocomplete, to do the autocomplete it is not necessary to save the file can be done with the data in the RAM, if you have the shortcut `Ctrl + S` busy then use another shortcut. The idea of updating a file is to replace the file so if you have a file of 100000 lines every time you add or remove a letter you will do it with the 100000 lines.

Comment: As I indicate to you the commercial publishers only update the file that is in the hard disk only when you press `Ctrl + S` or the application is closed since a dialogue always comes out if you want to update or you want to discard the information, do not you think there is a reasonable reason for all IDEs to do that ?, because the reason is that the task is too expensive.

Comment: I get it. Thanks for your advice. So maybe I need to just append the text into a list and make it the data?  But still how to do it automatically in PyQt5?  Is it still too heavy a task? Your advice please.

Comment: use the textChanged signal of QTextEdit to do some task, that signal is thrown every time the text is modified.

Comment: I think I'm understanding you, you have a list that you use as a source for the autocomplete, so I recommend you use textChanged and verify that there is a new word, not just a letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your method to be called every time you change the text in the QTextEdit just use the "textChanged" signal. I don't think it makes sense to store the text to a file in your case, but here is a working code for what you asked for:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.textedit = QTextEdit()
        self.textedit.textChanged.connect(self.save_text)
        layout.addWidget(self.textedit)

    def save_text(self):
        text = self.textedit.toPlainText()
        with open('mytextfile.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MyMainWindow()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```